# I can't connect to google APIs with the PHP client library

Tags: php, firebase, google-api-php-client

## I can't connect to google APIs with the PHP client library.

I started off with the getting started pages from google for a service account. but i'm stuck with this error witch doesnt reay tell me much about the problem

I also tried version 2.1.3 of the library with the same result.

here is my code.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once __DIR__ . '/../library/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./../secure/some-name-v2-cad7d18fcade.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileId = "0B9w-wSwYgo9ZU0toRFc3R1A5dlG";
$optParams = array();
$response = $driveService->files->get($fileId, $optParams); // Error on this line.

var_dump($response);
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Firebase\JWT\openssl_sign() in 
>   C:\www\library\google-api-php-client-2.2.0\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\src\JWT.php:196
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\www\library\google-api-php-client-2.2.0\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\src\JWT.php(167): 
>   Firebase\JWT\JWT::sign('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', '-----BEGIN PRIV...', 'RS256')
>
> #1 C:\www\library\google-api-php-client-2.2.0\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php(1267): 
>   Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode(Array, '-----BEGIN PRIV...', 'RS256')
>
> #2 C:\www\library\google-api-php-client-2.2.0\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php(418): 
>   Google\Auth\OAuth2->jwtEncode(Array, '-----BEGIN PRIV...', 'RS256')
>
> #3 C:\www\library\google-api-php-client-2.2.0\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php(451): 
>   Google\Auth\OAuth2->toJwt()
>
> #4 C:\www in C:\www\library\google-api-php-client-2.2.0\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\src\JWT.php on line 196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the openssl extension.

Uncomment (remove the `;` on) the line in your php.ini which says

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and restart your server.